# Create RDS DB User CloudFormation

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

As CloudFormation does not natively support creating a DB User for an RDS Database, I am looking for ways to do this via CustomResource. However, even if I write a CustomResource backed by a Lambda function, I do not see an RDS API endpoint that would allow me to add a user to a database instance.

Could anyone suggest potential ways to create a DB User for an Aurora Cluster backed by Postgres 10 database engine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I do not see an RDS API endpoint that would allow me to add a user to a database instance.

Usually you would set your custom resource to trigger after RDS is created. Thus, you can pass the RDS endpoint url to the lambda using, for example, function **environment variables**.

Practically [DependsOn](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html) attribute on your custom resource could be used to ensure that the custom resource triggers after the RDS is successfully created. Not really needed if you pass the RDS url though environmental variables.

Update code with example lambda which uses `pymysql`:

```
     
  MyLambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: index.lambda_handler
      Role: !Ref ExecRoleArn
      Runtime: python3.7
      Environment:
        Variables: 
          DB_HOSTNAME: !Ref DbHostname
          DB_USER: !Ref DbMasterUsername
          DB_PASSWORD: !Ref DbMasterPassword
          DB_NAME: !Ref DbName
      VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds: [!Ref SecurityGroupId]
        SubnetIds: !Ref SubnetIds
      Code:
        ZipFile: |
            import base64
            import json
            import os
            import logging
            import random
            import sys


            import pymysql
            import boto3

            rds_host  = os.environ['DB_HOSTNAME']
            rds_user = os.environ['DB_USER']
            rds_password = os.environ['DB_PASSWORD']
            rds_dbname = os.environ['DB_NAME']

            logger = logging.getLogger()
            logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

            try:
                
                conn = pymysql.connect(rds_host, 
                                       user=rds_user,
                                       passwd=rds_password, 
                                       db=rds_dbname, 
                                       connect_timeout=5)
            except:
                logger.error("ERROR: Unexpected error: Could not connect to MySql instance.")
                sys.exit()          

            def lambda_handler(event, context):

                print(json.dumps(event))

                with conn.cursor() as cur:

                    cur.execute("create table if not exists Employee (EmpID  int NOT NULL auto_increment, Name varchar(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (EmpID))")

                    conn.commit()

    
                return {
                    'statusCode': 200,
                    'body': ""
                }     


      Timeout: 60 # 
      MemorySize: 128
      Layers: 
        - arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:113088814899:layer:Klayers-python37-PyMySQL:1
```

Comment: I get the part of either using a different stack or DependsOn to be executed after the Database is created. However, the question is - how do I provision a DB User after the DB is created. I believe Lambda will have to work with the RDS API endpoint to make any changes. However, the RDS API does not expose any capability to create a DB User.

Comment: @NitinRastogi You will have to use mysql (or eqivalent to your db) client to connect to the database, and use SQL commands to create the user.

Comment: I am sorry, but how can I do that on a Lambda? As far as I know, Lambda does not support using the "traditional client connection methodology" like JDBC or any other database driver but rather we use RDS APIs for DB interactions.

Comment: @NitinRastogi I added an example of such lambda with `pymysql`. Please note  the use of lambda layer to provide `python37-PyMySQL` (its public layer). Obviously the example would need to be adjusted to create users or perform other operations which you require. Hope it will be useful.